# Paragraph ended before align* was complete - can't find the typo

Tags: align, debugging

This is the code in question

```
\end{align*} 
These correspond to translations $z \mapsto z + \lambda$
\begin{align*}
M \text{ is elliptic } &\iff M \text{ has exactly 2 complex conjugate fixed points } \\
&\iff M & \!\begin{aligned[t] \text{ is conjugate in } \SL_2{\mathbb{R}} \text{ to }
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix} \\  
\pi \le \theta \le \pi, \, \theta \neq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

I've been trying to debug it for an hour now. I've seen the past threads and know I should be looking for a newline inside the \align environment or a double slash in the last line, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Is this a copy paste?  You have `\begin{aligned[t]` without closing the `}`.

Comment: How do I never let this happen again? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `\begin{aligned[t]` without closing the `}`.  You then asked the obvious follow up of how you could have spotted this, and not have it happen again.

The easiest way that you could have spotted this is to have syntax highlighting in your editor.  Let's take what should be a compilable statement (the `{align*}` environment):

- In Overleaf, that segment is immediately highlighted at the offending spot (as well as the unbalanced `\begin{align*}` and `\end{aligned}`).
- In TeXWorks, all of `\begin{aligned[t] \text{ is conjugate in }` is highlighted in the "environment" color, indicating it thinks that is the environment name (this is admittedly a bit subtle if you're not looking for it).  Also, if you go past the offending part and type `}`, it will show the matching `{` in `\begin{aligned`.
- In TeXShop, if you go to the end of that segment and use `Source -> Close Current Environment` (ctrl-cmd-c on a Mac), it will say that the current environment is closed by `\end{aligned[t] \text{ is conjugate in }`.  As with TeXWorks, if you go past the offending part and type `}`, it will highlight everything from the unmatched `{` in `\begin{aligned` onward.
- I'm not sure about other editors.

The next step would be to comment out things that should be ok, and see if you still have the error.  Making your code into a compilable example and then commenting out lines, I get:

```tex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
%\end{align*} 
%These correspond to translations $z \mapsto z + \lambda$
\begin{align*}
%M \text{ is elliptic } &\iff M \text{ has exactly 2 complex conjugate fixed points } \\
&\iff M & \!\begin{aligned[t] \text{ is conjugate in } \SL_2{\mathbb{R}} \text{ to }
%\begin{pmatrix}
%\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
%\end{pmatrix} \\  
%\pi \le \theta \le \pi, \, \theta \neq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

which still has the same error and its message.  The next step is to isolate what part of the remaining lines is causing the problem.  Of the lines that are left, only one has more than one part to it, so we can break that line into multiple lines and comment out everything that we can.  That leaves us with:

```tex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
%\end{align*} 
%These correspond to translations $z \mapsto z + \lambda$
\begin{align*}
%M \text{ is elliptic } &\iff M \text{ has exactly 2 complex conjugate fixed points } \\
%&
%\iff M
%& \!
\begin{aligned[t]
%\text{ is conjugate in }
%\SL_2{\mathbb{R}}
%\text{ to }
%\begin{pmatrix}
%\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
%\end{pmatrix} \\  
%\pi \le \theta \le \pi, \, \theta \neq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

If we were still having trouble spotting the error, the next step would be to separate the `aligned` from the environment.  It still needs to be within a math environment, so we'll move it to `\[...\]`.  Doing that shows that our problem is with `aligned`, not `align*`, so we can comment out that:

```tex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
%\end{align*} 
%These correspond to translations $z \mapsto z + \lambda$
%\begin{align*}
%M \text{ is elliptic } &\iff M \text{ has exactly 2 complex conjugate fixed points } \\
%&
%\iff M
%& \!
%\end{align*} % moved from below
\[
\begin{aligned[t]
%\text{ is conjugate in }
%\SL_2{\mathbb{R}}
%\text{ to }
%\begin{pmatrix}
%\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
%\end{pmatrix} \\  
%\pi \le \theta \le \pi, \, \theta \neq 0
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

This still has the same error, and if we remove the commented lines, we get the 7 line example:

```tex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned[t]
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Hopefully, you would have spotted the error once you isolated the `\begin{aligned[t]` on its own line instead of needing to get to the 7 line example, but this does trim down the problem to avoid it ever happening again.